# Binary Search like concept to create subset data in R

Tags: r, dataset, binary-search

I have below dataset `w` and key variable `x` for two cases.

```
Case 1:
x = 4
w = c(1,2,4,4,4,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15)

Case2:
x = 12
w = c(1,2,4,4,4,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15)
```

I want to create a function which will search for `x` through dataset `w` and will subset original dataset to lower size dataset as per `x`'s location in `w`. Output will be a lower size dataset having upper bound value same as search key. Below is the function I am trying to write in R:

```
create_chunk <- function(val, tab, L=1L, H=length(tab))
{
  if(H >= L)
  {
    mid = L + ((H-L)/2)
    ## If the element is present within middle length
    if(tab[mid] > val)
    {
      ## subset the original data in reduced size and again do mid position value checking
      ## then subset the data
    } else
    {
      mid = mid + (mid/2)
      ## Increase the mid position to go for right side checking
    }
  }
}
```

In the output I am looking for below:

```
Output for Case 1:
Dataset containing: 1,2,4,4,4,4

Output for Case 2:
Dataset containing: 1,2,4,4,4,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12


    Please note:
    1. Dataset may contain duplicate values for search key and 
       all the duplicate values are expected in the output dataset.
    2. I have huge size datasets (say around 2M rows) from 
       where I am trying to subset smaller dataset as per my requirement of search key.
```

**New Update: Case 3**

Input Data:

```
                 date    value size     stockName
1 2016-08-12 12:44:43 10093.40    4 HWA IS Equity
2 2016-08-12 12:44:38 10093.35    2 HWA IS Equity
3 2016-08-12 12:44:47 10088.00    2 HWA IS Equity
4 2016-08-12 12:44:52 10089.95    1 HWA IS Equity
5 2016-08-12 12:44:53 10089.95    1 HWA IS Equity
6 2016-08-12 12:44:54 10088.95    1 HWA IS Equity
```

Search Key is: `10089.95` in value column.

Expected Output is:

```
                 date    value size     stockName
1 2016-08-12 12:44:47 10088.00    2 HWA IS Equity
2 2016-08-12 12:44:54 10088.95    1 HWA IS Equity
3 2016-08-12 12:44:52 10089.95    1 HWA IS Equity
4 2016-08-12 12:44:53 10089.95    1 HWA IS Equity
```

Comment: what's the problem with your own function?

Comment: I am not getting success for 2nd dataset. Also I wanted suggestion about picking duplicate values if exists for the matching variable.

Comment: It seems you're looking for `?findInterval` -- `w[seq_len(findInterval(4, w))]`

Comment: @alexis_laz This is exactly what I thought of but it seems the OP's focus is `O(log n)` instead of `O(n)`.

Comment: @m0h3n : `findInterval`, apart from some initial checks, does not make a linear scan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this which takes care of duplicate values. In case of duplicates, the highest position of which will be returned. Please note that `A` should be in non-decreasing order.

```
binSearch <- function(A, value, left=1, right=length(A)){
  if (left > right)
    return(-1)
  middle <- (left + right) %/% 2
  if (A[middle] == value){
    while (A[middle] == value)
        middle<-middle+1
    return(middle-1)
    }
  else {
    if (A[middle] > value)
        return(binSearch(A, value, left, middle - 1))
    else
        return(binSearch(A, value, middle + 1, right))
    }
}

w[1:binSearch(w,x1)]
# [1] 1 2 4 4 4 4
w[1:binSearch(w,x2)]
# [1]  1  2  4  4  4  4  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

However, as its mentioned in the comments, you could simply use `findInterval` to achieve the same:

```
w[1:findInterval(x1,w)]
```

As you know, binary search has order of `log(n)` but as stated in `?findInterval`, it also benefits from `log(n)` since the length of the first argument is one:

> The function findInterval finds the index of one vector x in another, vec, where the latter must be non-decreasing. Where this is trivial, equivalent to apply( outer(x, vec, ">="), 1, sum), as a matter of fact, the internal algorithm uses interval search ensuring O(n * log(N)) complexity where n <- length(x) (and N <- length(vec)). For (almost) sorted x, it will be even faster, basically O(n).

**EDIT**

As per your edit and your new setting, you could do this (suppose your data is in `df`):

```
o <- order(df$value)
rows <- o[1:findInterval(key, df$value[o])]
df[rows,]
```

Or equivalently, using the proposed `binSearch` function:

```
o <- order(df$value)
rows <- o[1:binSearch(df$value[o], key)]
df[rows,]
```

**data**

```
x1 <- 4
x2 <- 12
w <- c(1,2,4,4,4,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15)
key <- 10089.95
```

Comment: Yes exactly, this is what I was trying for. Thank you. But still I am not successfully able to modify it for data frame. Say if the `w` is a data frame with two columns `col1:(1,2,4,4,4,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15)` and `col2:(4,2,1,2,3,6,6,7,8,9,11,12,14,14,16)`. If `col1` is the column for matching. Search key `x2` remains same. Then how the code can be modified for the same?

Comment: Can you please look into new update in the original problem? I have updated new case for data frame.

Comment: I have just gave a snapshot of the data. In original data I have 11 million data rows.

Comment: your update looks like working fine. But can you suggest modification in the original binSearch code you wrote for this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple solution and you can build your function out of this commands. Of course you have to check if `x` is in `w`, but that's your part :-)

```
x <- 12
w <- c(1,2,4,4,4,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15)

index <- which(x == w)

w_new <- w[1:index[length(index)]]
print(w_new)
#[1]  1  2  4  4  4  4  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Comment: This is right, but x == w means, x will go through searching in rows of w, isn't it? I am trying to avoid that linear search and trying to determine from mid position value of array. I hope you got my requirement.

Comment: But even when you use 2M rows, the `which`function is not slow in searching `x`in `w`. Why do you want to avoid the `which` function?

Comment: I do not want to go matching and finding index. Instead I want to decrease my dataset size by matching only one value that is mid-point value. I assume logically it should reduce execution time. Please correct me if I am wrong.